# Why nested MongoDB schema is slower than the flat?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Initially I had the next flat schema:

```
{
    _id:
    name:
    surname:
    courseID:
    courseName:
}
```

Later I've used `group` aggregate in MongoDB and generated this new nested schema:

```
{
    _id: {
        _id:,
        student: {
            name:
            surname:
        },
        course: {
            id:
            name:
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run a query, it runs on flat schema in `0.7sec` but in nested one it takes `1.02sec`.
So the question is, what I do wrong? Because I've read that the performance on nested schema should be better than the flatten one.
I have 1M records in my collection

For generating of the nested schema I was using:

```
db.nested.save(
db.flat.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            student: {
                name: "$studentname",
                surname: "$studentsurname"
            },
            course: {
                id: "$courseid",
                name: "$coursename"
            }
        }
    }
}
], { allowDiskUse: true }).toArray()
)
```

Maybe there are options how can I improve my query for generating a new nested collection?